# Thumbnail image of Links in my Community page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been searching hard on when a user pastes a link in the community page, and posts it. Then just below the link - a small image of the site and brief description of the site appears.

This is similar to when you post a link in Linkedin, and when you post it, then in the post automatically a small image of the website that this link points to appears, and also a brief descritption of the site, which I believe is the title.

I have searched a lot, but could not find a place to start on how to do this. If anyone can give me a starting point, it would be highly appreciated.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

This really would be highly valuable for all sorts of applications. Doing a quick SO and Google search, I found one *service* that has an API for this: https://www.url2png.com.

I'm not sure, but it would seem that this type of function would have to be done backend with software installed on your server. This makes sense as we're working with rendering images; and current browsers (through Javascript or APIs) don't yet seem to have the ability to render images. (Anyone provide links to documentation in the comments if I'm wrong about this?)

#### Update

Here's another one I found that has command-line open-source code: http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/